# Cordova local notification dynamically

Tags: cordova, dynamic, localnotification

I am using this **https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications** for local notificationin cordova.

But I want to implement this dynamically. Before call to this notification plugin every time, it should call the ajax web service and get the notification content (title, message, etc).

Suppose the value notification_show is true from ajax web service then only show the notification otherwise it will not show. How to do it.

Comment: You could try to implement push notifications instead, which are generated form the server and you could control when they're launched